Why are certain mounted volumes not listed by diskutil?
mount and df show that disk1s5 is a mounted volume:
bash-3.2$ mount
/dev/disk1s4s1 on / (apfs, sealed, local, read-only, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s2 on /System/Volumes/Preboot (apfs, local, journaled, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s6 on /System/Volumes/VM (apfs, local, noexec, journaled, noatime, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s5 on /System/Volumes/Update (apfs, local, journaled, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s1 on /System/Volumes/Data (apfs, local, journaled, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /System/Volumes/Data/home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
bash-3.2$ df -h
Filesystem       Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s4s1  233Gi  8.5Gi  149Gi     6%  356049 1561586480    0%   /
devfs           209Ki  209Ki    0Bi   100%     722          0  100%   /dev
/dev/disk1s2    233Gi  1.7Gi  149Gi     2%    2019 1561586480    0%   /System/Volumes/Preboot
/dev/disk1s6    233Gi  4.0Gi  149Gi     3%       4 1561586480    0%   /System/Volumes/VM
/dev/disk1s5    233Gi  3.8Mi  149Gi     1%      21 1561586480    0%   /System/Volumes/Update
/dev/disk1s1    233Gi   69Gi  149Gi    32%  594098 1561586480    0%   /System/Volumes/Data
map auto_home     0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0          0  100%   /System/Volumes/Data/home

However, disk1s5 does not appear in diskutil list:
bash-3.2$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         250.7 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +250.7 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     74.2 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 1.9 GB     disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.2 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            9.2 GB     disk1s4
   5:              APFS Snapshot com.apple.os.update-... 9.2 GB     disk1s4s1
   6:                APFS Volume VM                      4.3 GB     disk1s6

diskutil info does show information about disk1s5:
bash-3.2$ diskutil info disk1s5
   Device Identifier:         disk1s5
   Device Node:               /dev/disk1s5
   Whole:                     No
   Part of Whole:             disk1

   Volume Name:               Update
   Mounted:                   Yes
   Mount Point:               /System/Volumes/Update

   Partition Type:            41504653-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   File System Personality:   APFS
   Type (Bundle):             apfs
   Name (User Visible):       APFS
   Owners:                    Enabled

   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Booter Disk:               disk1s2
   Recovery Disk:             disk1s3
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  PCI-Express
   SMART Status:              Verified
   Volume UUID:               BE235512-940B-4A80-A1C7-7B6CB924E1D6
   Disk / Partition UUID:     BE235512-940B-4A80-A1C7-7B6CB924E1D6

   Disk Size:                 250.7 GB (250685575168 Bytes) (exactly 489620264 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         4096 Bytes

   Volume Used Space:         4.0 MB (4034560 Bytes) (exactly 7880 512-Byte-Units)
   Container Total Space:     250.7 GB (250685575168 Bytes) (exactly 489620264 512-Byte-Units)
   Container Free Space:      159.9 GB (159881302016 Bytes) (exactly 312268168 512-Byte-Units)
   Allocation Block Size:     4096 Bytes

   Media OS Use Only:         Yes
   Media Read-Only:           No
   Volume Read-Only:          No

   Device Location:           Internal
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               Yes
   Hardware AES Support:      Yes

   This disk is an APFS Volume.  APFS Information:
   APFS Container:            disk1
   APFS Physical Store:       disk0s2
   Fusion Drive:              No
   Encrypted:                 No
   FileVault:                 No
   Sealed:                    No
   Locked:                    No

So why doesn't diskutil list show it? I thought diskutil list would always show all volumes, but it seems that certain mounted volumes are hidden.

Just out of interest: (a) can you see the partition mounted in the Finder? (b) Can you see it in the Disk Utility GUI application? (c) Have you ejected the partition?

@Greenonline a) Yes b) No, although as I understand it Disk Utility hides certain volumes (e.g. Recovery) so that may just be expected. In Disk Utility, disk1 is listed with volume count 5, but I can only view disk1s1, disk1s4, and disk1s4s1, even when I go to View > Show All Devices. c) I just now tried ejecting it and couldn't because it was in use. I guess could try forcing it but that makes me nervous.

Yes, don't force eject (not yet anyway).

Just to confirm that I see the same thing with different numbering disk3s6. My Update volume is a bit larger - using 18.8 MB. What do you get with ls -la /System/Volumes/Update? Suspect related to macOS updates - some files there go back over 3 years. (Intel iMac 2019)

The Update volume is what macOS uses during updates and upgrades of macOS. It is mounted at /System/Volumes/Update.
You can view /System/Volumes in Finder or Terminal. It is fairly obvious in Finder that there are four volumes which are mounted there - Preboot, Update, VM and the read/write boot volume. Here is mine in Finder:

Some of the files/folders are more than 3 years old on my 2019 iMac. So if it gets large a bit of judicious pruning might be in order. But I don't recommend that. Certainly don't try to delete the volume.
I don't know why it is hidden by Disk Utility and diskutil. My guess is that someone at Apple thought it would be good idea!  And you don't need to know about it.
A helpful link from Howard Oakley: Some Mirages in the File System.
